# How to Require Another Custom Class Using Puppet

Tags: puppet

If I have two class's in my own puppet module and class 'b' has a dependency on class 'a'. How can I express this in my `require` statement:

```
# a.pp
class rehan::a {
    package { 'javaruntime':
        ensure   => latest,
        provider => chocolatey
    }
}

# b.pp
class rehan::b {
    file { 'C:\foo':
        ensure  => present,
        require => Package['?????']
    }
}

# site.pp
node default {
    include rehan::a
    include rehan::b
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to express a dependency of class `b` on class `a` (and also ensure that `a` is in the catalog):

```
class rehan::b {
    require rehan::a
}
```

If you just one resource on rehan::b to depend on class `A`:

```
class rehan::b {
    include rehan::a  # ensure the class is in the catalog
    file { 'C:\foo':
        ensure  => present,
        require => Class['rehan::a'],
    }
}
```

You can also express this relationship anywhere with `Class['rehan::a'] -> Class['rehan::b']` (assuming both are included in the catalog).